# Broken JavaScript Registry in Plone 3.1.7

Tags: plone

I created a javascript file TTW for a quick fix to something i was working with, and when i went to the portal_javascripts and added it there i was met with this error upon saving:

Exception Type:     CompilerError
Exception Value: Path element may not be empty in 'portal/http://www.example.com/portal_skins/cloud.js'

I get that same error every time i attempt to navigate to the portal_javascripts through the ZMI, it's obvious that I incorrectly entered the id of my file, but now I can't even fix it.

I was able to find this example of someone with a similiar issue, but I have no how to go about his fix
http://markmail.org/message/zbjhjoezz2h423yr#query:+page:1+mid:yhgjekdkwnegwqen+state:results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

http://example.com/portal_javascripts/unregisterResource?id=[your_js_resource_id]

Comment: ah you are a life saver, I'll have to remember that one

Comment: Cool.  never heard of that - I was going to suggest something convoluted involving exporting javascript registry from portal_setup, fixing it and importing it.  it's not even a valid error - on a linux system, a path containing // is perfectly legal: works in my apache